# Arduino Blink example does not run after upload from eclipse

Tags: arduino, avr, avrdude, eclipse, blink

I just started with my first Arduino project. I am trying out the Blink example. I have set up eclipse for arduino 1.0 and the code compiles without errors (both lib project and blink project).
I used the tutorial at: http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse
When I upload the code to the board using the upload button avrdude says successful upload but the code never runs. I am using an unmodified blink code supplied with an additional main() to sequence the init, setup and loop.

What am I missing? Can someone help me out?

Edit: 
Here is the code I am trying to run. It is the eclipse blink project linked at the end of the tutorial above. Link: https://github.com/ricovangenugten/Arduino-Blink-Eclipse-Project/tree/master/Blink

Comment: Does it work if you upload it with Arduino IDE?

Comment: "with an additional main()"... So you have 2 mains?

Comment: It works if I upload the code using the arduino IDE. When I add a main function to sequence the code in eclipse IDE it does not work. My library ArduinoCore does not have a main.

Comment: I am still unclear as to what you have done. It sounds like you are saying that the original code works, but when you change it, it no longer works. If this is the case edit the question to add the code you are adding.

Comment: Have you tried pressing reset on the board after loading code?

Comment: Eclipse user here.  The Arduino IDE does a lot behind the scenes, one of which is to supply a main function that calls 1) a pre-built system init() function, 2) the user's setup() function, and 3) loops over the user's loop() function. Eclipse works like any other environment: it compiles and links only what you provide (including any libraries you point it at). As with other C/C++ environments, main() is a user-supplied function.  That would be the first function in code s/he linked to, which would not need to be supplied when compiling in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: If the only difference between working and not working is the environment (and properly corresponding presence or not of your main() function), then the only thing left is the possibility your IDE and eclipse project-configurations - including the libraries - may not be targeting the system you think they are.  The logical-to-physical pin assignments are different, e.g., between a mega2560 earlier Arduinos built around the 168 or 328 processors. Check your configurations. And look for a blink signal on one of the other output pins.

Comment: I too have come to the conclusion that its an environment thing. What I have not been able to figure out is how do I debug the eclipse IDE setup. I have followed the eclipse setup instructions but the only thing I could not figure out were the recommended versions of winavr, eclipse, etc. I went with the latest. That may be a reason why the setup isn't working for me.

Comment: @user1159898: It took me a while to get my environment up and running. If I can help point you in the right direction, contact me through my profile.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem when using the AVR Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been open for a while and I have been scratching my head for a long time but it finally worked just minutes ago!!!

This is what finally worked for me:
http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse#Arduino_core_library
In this tutorial, scroll down to "Arduino target reset for uploading" look under the Linux section for the following instructions:
*"Instead of using programmer stk500v1 with AVRdude, use programmer arduino and it creates the reset automatically. In the project properties, change AVR -> AVRDude, Programmer tab, Programmer configuration. Edit the existing one or add a new one."*

Although I am using win7 x64 this change worked for me when I used it with a baud rate of 115200.